# How can I simplify this triplanar material so that I only need to feed my texture into one slot instead of three?

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders

I found a setup for a tri-planar shader online and it gives good results for me so I quite like it. But every time I want to swap the texture I have to swap it for each of the texture nodes. That feels like it is unnecessary trouble so I was wondering if there is a way to simplify it so that I can easily swap them. Something like instancing the texture nodes to inherit the texture swap.

The same problem applies to the "Mapping" nodes only that there I have a free slot for scale on each node so I think I can just control each of them simultaneously with one node that gives a constant value.

Thanks for your help!

[image: shader setup]

Comment: Place the texture node (or mapping) in its own node group. Modifying the node group will impact all its instances. This is not a perfect solution compared to some input or node class as you suggest, though...

Comment: That would solve it! :) 
I am not sure where I can upvote your answer but thank you a lot for the help! :)